# How can i Compare two excel sheet in .Net2.0?

Tags: .net, excel, vba, c#-2.0

I am having two text files ( which is a comma separated file).The template of the two file is given below.

```
            SD,CurrentDate,RecordCount
    NI,FirstName,LastName,Place,Language
    EQ,Degree,University,Year,Aggregate
    ED,CurrentDate,RecordCount
```

The Data in the first file - one.txt

```
          SD,13/06/2010,6
          NI,Rajesh,kumar,xxxx,english
          EQ,X,Stateboard,2004,75
          EQ,XII,Stateboard,2006,85
          EQ,B.E,Oxford,2008,79
             ED,13/06/2010,6
```

The Data in the Second file - Second.txt

```
          SD,13/06/2010,6
          NI,Rajesh,kumar,,english
          EQ,X,,2004,75
          EQ,XII,Stateboard,2006,
          EQ,,Oxford,2008,79
          ED,13/06/2010,6
```

Now I have populted the value of the one.txt to the "sheet1" of Excel sheet(Output.xls) and then i have populated

the value of the Second.txt to the "sheet2" of Excel sheet(Output.xls) by using the .Net code.

Now i want to compare two sheets data and populte the difference in the "sheet3".

The o/p of the "Sheet3" will have.

```
    Cell1       Cell2           Cell3           Cell4       Cell5
    SD:True     CurrentDate:True    RecordCount:True
    NI:True     FirstName:True      LastName:True       Place:False   Language:True
    EQ:True     Degree:True     University:False    Year:True   Aggregate:True
    EQ:True     Degree:True     University:True     Year:True   Aggregate:False
    EQ:True     Degree:False        University:True     Year:True   Aggregate:True
    SD:True     CurrentDate:True    RecordCount:True
```

How can i compare this two sheets? Is it possible through VBA? Can i able to call the VBA code in .Net?Please anyone  provide me the solution?

Comment: Surely it would be much easier/efficient to compare the raw data loaded from the 2 text files rather than iterating over 2 spreadsheets?

Comment: @Alex.K :By using .Net ,I have populated the value in two sheets.Is it possible by using VBA code calling in .Net

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like to compare 2 sheets after you have manually or melodramatically populated the values to. In this case the following code will do the job, but you have to modify the parts that will insert the column name before the boolean value

```
Dim objEX as new Excel.Application
    objEX.Visible = True
    ' Optional if you want to see what is
    ' going on in EXCEL while your code is being executed.


objEX.Workbooks.Open "C:\My Files\Filename.xls"
'Make sure you put the right path of the excel workbook you want to open

With objEX
    .Sheets(1).Activate
    .Range("a1").Select

    .Sheets(2).Activate
    .Range("a1").Select

    .Sheets(3).Activate
    .Range("a1").Select


    'assuming the populated data starts at Cell A1
    For i = 0 To 6      'because you have 6 rows
        For j = 0 To 5  'because you have 5 columns
            If .Sheets(1).ActiveCell.Offset(i, j).Value = .Sheets(2).ActiveCell.Offset(i, j).Value Then
                .Sheets(3).ActiveCell.Offset(i, j).Value = "True"
            Else
                .Sheets(3).ActiveCell.Offset(i, j).Value = "False"
            End If
        Next
    Next


    .ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'Saves the changes you have done

    .ActiveWorkbook.Close
    'Closes the workbook


    .Quit
    'Quits excel instance and releases the process from task manager

End With

    Set objEX = Nothing
    'Garbage Collection and making sure memory is released to other processes.
```